# How to check if apk is zip aligned?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publishing, zipalign

Is there any possibility to check if an apk file is zip aligned?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just found the verification command: `zipalign -c -v 4 application.apk`

From here : [ZipAlign verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543520/zipalign-verification)